# java util date value of string

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

This is a method in an EJB for adding booking, I'm trying to set a to value of String Arr because Arr is a string which gets the form value in the Servlet and I want to do the same for d to value of String Dept. I'm using `java.util.Date`, it works for `java.sql.Date` but not for `java.util.Date`.

```
public void addBooking(String Arr,  String Dept, String username, String roomnum){
    BookingTableClass booking = new BookingTableClass();

    Date a= Date.valueOf(Arr);//the problem is in these four lines
    booking.setarrivalDate(a);
    Date d= Date.valueOf(Dept);
    booking.setdeptDate(d);

            booking.setCustomerUsername(username);  
    Long rmnum = Long.valueOf(roomnum);
    booking.setRoomNumber(rmnum);}
```

Comment: You've shown us **where** the problem is, but not **what** the problem is. Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a java.util.Date into a java.sql.Date object like this:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
```

That is, you obtain the java.util.Date equivalent in milliseconds and then use this value to initialize the java.sql.Date object.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new   SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
  Date a=null;
  try {
   a = formatter.parse(Arr);
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  booking.setarrivalDate(a);
  Date d=null;
  try {
   d = formatter.parse(Dept);
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're not using a correct format for the Date type and you have to specify the format that you're using, for this purpose use SimpleDateFormat class.

```
SimpleDateFormat textFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String paramDateAsString = "2007-12-25";
Date myDate = null;

myDate = textFormat.parse(paramDateAsString);
```

Hope it helps. Best regards.